# Facebook publishActivity: No error, but no activity published

Tags: php, facebook, rest, dashboard

implementing publishActivity in PHP using the REST API using this code:

```
$activity = array(
    'message' => '{*actor*} did something.',
    'action_link' => array(
        'text' => 'Play Travians',
        'href' => WEBROOT
    )
);
$activity = $facebook->api_client->dashboard_publishActivity($activity);
```

I get a 15-digit number returned and no errors, however no activity appears in the logged in account or friends of this account.

Help appreciated.

Carlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a Feed post.

Comment: Thanks... what I'm looking for is to publish into the "Recent Activity" tab as in this image: http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/9840/publishactivityonfacebo.png